HAProxy cfg problem in combination with docker swarm replica backend
I have a very basic test setup which doesn't work and I was hoping someone can point me into the right directions
So, for this experiment I use a docker compose file (with Docker Swarm):
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    image: nmatsui/hello-world-api
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - ha_network
    ports: 
      - "3000"

  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:latest
    volumes:
      - ./files/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
    ports:
      - "80:80" 
    networks:
      - ha_network

networks:
  ha_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

Now what happens when I start this, I see 2 backends spinning up, but haproxy won't start complaining about the haproxy.cfg, which in my case is:
global
    log stdout format raw local0
    maxconn 4096
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client  30s
    timeout server  30s
    retries 3

resolvers docker
    nameserver dns 127.0.0.11:53
    resolve_retries 3
    timeout resolve 1s
    timeout connect 1s
    timeout server 5s

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend app-backend

backend app-backend
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /health
    server-template backend 1-10 backend:3000 check resolvers docker

The error is

[NOTICE]   (1) : haproxy version is 3.0.5-8e879a5 [NOTICE]   (1) :
path to executable is /usr/local/sbin/haproxy [ALERT]    (1) : config
: parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:20] : 'timeout' expects
'retry' or 'resolve' and  as arguments got 'connect'. [ALERT]
(1) : config : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:21] :
'timeout' expects 'retry' or 'resolve' and  as arguments got
'server'. [ALERT]    (1) : config : parsing
[/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:30]: Missing LF on last line, file
might have been truncated at position 69. [ALERT]    (1) : config :
Error(s) found in configuration file :
/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg [ALERT]    (1) : config : Fatal
errors found in configuration.

So haproxy doesn't say what exactly the problem is (I think it is in the last line). Any suggestions what the problem might be or how to debug this and where I can find more details about connecting HaProxy with replicas?

" 'timeout' expects 'retry' or 'resolve' and as arguments got 'connect'."  " 'timeout' expects 'retry' or 'resolve' and as arguments got 'server'."

Ah I see it now, thnx!!
